# How to achieve nomenclature entries like: symbol, Description, Dimension and unit, etc?

Tags: nomenclature, units

The title is pretty much I want to ask. More detail, the nomenclature entries should be sorted in groups like:

```
 Nomenclature

   Acronyms
    Symbol  Description     % no Dimensions and Units 
    ...

   Greek Symbols
    Symbol  Description             Dimensions     Units
    ...

   Roman Symbols
    Symbol  Description             Dimensions     Units
    S       Surface area vector     L^2            m^2
    ...
   Superscripts
    Symbol  Description     % no Dimensions and Units 
    ...
   Dimensionless Numbers
    Symbol  Description     Definition
    ...
```

e.g. expected entries like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My current nomenclature settings for grouping [book class]:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------
%                        Nomenclature
%----------------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols and Abbrev.}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
   \item[\textbf{Acronyms}] }{%                  A - Acronyms
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
     \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%            R - Roman
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
        \item[\textbf{•} Symbols }]}{%          G - Greek
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
           \item[\textbf{Superscripts  }]}{{%          S - Superscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Subscripts }]}{{%                 U - Subscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Other Symbols }]}%            X - Other Symbols
                    {{}}}}}}}}}}
%\ifpdf
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\hspace{1 em}#1}%{\hspace{1.5 em}#1}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
```

But how to extend it with `Dimensions` and `Units`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The documentation of the nomenclature package includes code to put everything in a longtable environment, but this involves some hacking of the `.ist` file.  A simpler approach that may be sufficient is just to define some helper macros that work within in an ordinary list:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl,etoolbox,ragged2e,siunitx}

\newcommand{\DimensUnits}[2]{\hfill\makebox[8em]{#1\hfill}%
\makebox[4em]{#2\hfill}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\insertnomheaders}{\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
\textbf{Description}\DimensUnits{\textbf{Dimensions}}{\textbf{Units}}}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{S}{Superscripts}{% 
  \ifstrequal{#1}{U}{Subscripts}{%   
  \ifstrequal{#1}{X}{Other Symbols}{}}}}}}]
  \insertnomheaders
  }

\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}
\newcommand{\nomwithdim}[5]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\nomdescr{#3}\DimensUnits{#4}{#5}}}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\nomwithdim{R}{\(a,b,c\)}{half axes of ellipsoid}{L}{\si{m}}
\nomwithdim{R}{\(C\)}{dimensionless coefficient (e.g.\ for drag model)}{--}{1}
\nomwithdim{G}{\( \varepsilon_0 \)}{vacuum permittivity}{F/L}{\si{F.m^{-1}}}

\printnomenclature[6em]
\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\printnomenclature` sets the space available for the symbols.  We then set each line as an `\item` whose label is the symbol, followed by a paragraph of fixed width containing the description, followed by a box for dimensions and finally a box for units.  `etoolbox` has been loaded to avoid the deprecated `ifthen` package. `sunitx` has been loaded for printing the units.

Of course, to compile this you need to run the file through (pdf)latex, then run

```
makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls
```

with "`file`" replaced (both times) by your jobname, i.e. where the main file is `file.tex`.  You then need to run (pdf)latex again.

*ADDED in response to comment* Here is a version with different styling for different categories.  *UPDATED again* Now with optional arguments to pass to the sorting keys.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl,etoolbox,ragged2e,siunitx,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\newcommand{\DimensUnits}[2]{\hfill\makebox[8em]{#1\hfill}%
\makebox[4em]{#2\hfill}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\DefinitionCol}[1]{\hfill\parbox[t]{12em}{#1}\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\nomsubtitle}[1]{\item[\large\bfseries #1]}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{\def\nomtemp{\csname nomstart#1\endcsname}\nomtemp}

\newcommand{\nomstartR}{\nomsubtitle{Roman Symbols}%
  \item[\bfseries Symbol]%
  \textbf{Description}\DimensUnits{\textbf{Dimensions}}{\textbf{Units}}}
\newcommand{\nomstartG}{\nomsubtitle{Greek Symbols}%
  \item[\bfseries Symbol]%
  \textbf{Description}\DimensUnits{\textbf{Dimensions}}{\textbf{Units}}}
\newcommand{\nomstartD}{\nomsubtitle{Dimensionless Numbers}%
  \item[\bfseries Symbol]\textbf{Description}\DefinitionCol{\textbf{Definition}}}

\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}
\newcommand{\nomwithdim}[5]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\nomdescr{#3}\DimensUnits{#4}{#5}}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeR}[5][]{\nomwithdim{R#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeG}[5][]{\nomwithdim{G#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeD}[4][]{\nomenclature[D#1]{#2}{\nomdescr{#3}\DefinitionCol{#4}}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\nomtypeR[abc]{\(a,b,c\)}{half axes of ellipsoid}{L}{\si{m}}
\nomtypeR[C]{\(C\)}{dimensionless coefficient (e.g.\ for drag model)}{--}{1}
\nomtypeG{\( \varepsilon_0 \)}{vacuum permittivity}{F/L}{\si{F.m^{-1}}}
\nomtypeD{\( \mathcal A_r \)}{Archimedes number}{\(\displaystyle
\frac{d^3g\rho_c\abs{\Delta\rho}}{\mu_c^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\mathcal
E_0^3}{\mathcal M_0}} \)}
\nomtypeR[CC]{\(\mathbf{C}\)}{another dimensionless coefficient}{--}{1}
\nomtypeR[A]{\(A\)}{a dimensionless coefficient}{--}{1}
\nomtypeR[Z]{\(Z\)}{a dimensionless coefficient}{--}{1}

\printnomenclature[6em]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine! Btw, I have updated my post: how to make different groups with different style?

Comment: That is not too hard a modification: (1) create a custom command for each style with the formatting and (2) change the `\nomgroup` code to write an appropriate `\item[]` followed by an appropriate header command.

Comment: Such a solution now added above.

Comment: Now it works nearly perfectly. Only remaining issue is that the order of symbols: e.g. {`$S$`}, {`\textbf{S}`}, {`\(S\)`}, {`S`} will be sorted differently. Is there a way sorting the symbols alphabetically?

Comment: Now added via optional arguments to specify sorting key.

Comment: Great, what is the parameter to control the length of Description column?

Comment: It is the `4cm` in `\nomdescr`

Comment: I tried add some spacing before and after each Group's name, because if the last entry has two or more lines, the spacing is too narrow. \\ or `\vspace(1em)` seems not working

Comment: `\newcommand{\nomsubtitle}[1]{\vspace{7ex plus 2ex minus 1ex}%
\item[\large\bfseries #1]\mbox{}\vspace{5ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}}` will work.

Comment: If the list of symbols is large and extends on to the next page, I would want the column headings (**Symbol**, **Description**, **Dimension**, etc) to appear on the next page as well. How to ensure that such thing happens?

Comment: @Tarun Sounds like a new question...

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I have been looking forward to get an answer to this question for a long time. I don't know how things appeared  for others, but for me headings didn't appear in the next page. I have already posted a question for that and liked with this question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197248/for-a-group-of-symbols-how-to-get-column-headingsdescription-in-the-next-page

Comment: both of the codes led to an empty page for me. any reasons why

Comment: @AmarjitSingh Did you run `makeindex` - I have added instructions to the answer.  If that doesn't work then post a question giving details.