# Sharelatex - Nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, sharelatex

Recently, Sharelatex added the possibility of using `\makeindex`. However, I would like to add a nomenclature, preferably in the same style as in this topic [How to achieve nomenclature entries like: symbol, Description, Dimension and unit, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni). 
However, if I add the code of the answer in that topic, the nomenclature is not printed. It seems that the `nomencl` package does not work in Sharelatex, but that would be strange since Sharelatex now supports `\makeindex`. 
Should this not work in Sharelatex, is there then a workaround to use such a nomenclature in Sharelatex without using the `nomencl` package?

Comment: makeindex has to run in a special way for the nomencl package. We've just added in support for this at ShareLaTeX today, so it should now work. Drop me an email at james@sharelatex.com if not.

Comment: @jpallen Can you make that an answer please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was essentially a feature request for ShareLaTeX that has now been addressed.