# For a group of symbols, how to get column headings(description) in the next page?

Tags: nomenclature, units

This question is with reference to the answer provided in [How to achieve nomenclature entries like: symbol, Description, Dimension and unit, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni)

I am able to achieve different styling for different categories. Sorting is also done similar to the way illustrated in the figure.
[image]

However what is happening is that if a category starts on one page and continues over the next page headings do not appear in the next page. 
I want to be able to get headings in the next page if the contents do not fit in one page. Please suggest a way to be able to get headings in a new page.

Comment: You could use the `longtable` package to typeset this. It features header lines that will be added whenever the table is entering a new page.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. Could you please let me know how to do that? NOTE: This question was with respect to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni. It would be great if the answer is an extension to the ideas presented in that question. Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation to post my query in that question. Hence I was forced to frame my own.

Comment: It is not obvious how to integrate `longtable` with `nomencl`. The package `nomentbl` is supposed to do just what you want, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: use glossaries instead of nomencl, it has longtable styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer. Thanks to @schtandard. I modified his code a bit and was able to get something closer to what I need.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newglossary*{nodimennum}{Dimensionless Numbers}
\newglossary*{greeksym}{Greek Symbols}

\glsaddkey{dimension}
  {--}
  {\glsentrydimension}
  {\Glsentrydimension}
  {\glsdimension}
  {\Glsdimension}
  {\GLSdimension}
\glsaddkey{unit}
  {--}
  {\glsentryunit}
  {\Glsentryunit}
  {\glsunit}
  {\Glsunit}
  {\GLSunit}
\glsaddkey{definition}
  {--}
  {\glsentrydefinition}
  {\Glsentrydefinition}
  {\glsdefinition}
  {\Glsdefinition}
  {\GLSdefinition}
\glssetnoexpandfield{dimension}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\newcommand*\dimensionname{Dimension}
\newcommand*\unitname{Unit}
\newcommand*\definitionname{Definition}

\newglossarystyle{nodimennum}{%
  \glspatchLToutput
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    %{\begin{center}\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{.2\linewidth}p{.35\linewidth}p{.35\linewidth}}}%
    {\begin{longtabu}{lXX}}%
    {\end{longtabu}}%
    %{\end{longtable}\end{center}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule
    \bfseries \symbolname &
    \bfseries \descriptionname &
    \bfseries \definitionname
    \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} &
    \glsentrydefinition{##1} \tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\glspenaltygroupskip}%
  \fi
}
\newglossarystyle{physsym}{%
  \glspatchLToutput
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    %{\begin{center}\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l l l}}%
    {\begin{longtabu}{l X X X}}%
    {\end{longtabu}}%
    %{\end{longtable}\end{center}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule \bfseries \symbolname &
    \bfseries \descriptionname &
    \bfseries \dimensionname &
    \bfseries \unitname
    \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} &
    \glsentrydimension{##1} &
    \glsentryunit{##1} \tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\glspenaltygroupskip}%
  \fi
}
\makeglossaries
\begingroup\renewcommand*\glsdefaulttype{greeksym}
  \newglossaryentry{eps0}{
    name={eps0},
    symbol={\(\varepsilon_0\)},
    description={vacuum permittivity},
    dimension={\(\mathrm F / \mathrm L\)},
    unit={\si{\farad\per\meter}},
  }
\endgroup

\begingroup\renewcommand*\glsdefaulttype{nodimennum}
  \newglossaryentry{zero}{
    name={0},
    symbol={\(0\)},
    description={zero},
    definition={the smallest natural number},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{one}{
    name={1},
    symbol={\(1\)},
    description={one},
    definition={\(0 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{two}{
    name={1},
    symbol={\(2\)},
    description={two},
    definition={\(1 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{three}{
    name={3},
    symbol={\(3\)},
    description={three},
    definition={\(2 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{four}{
    name={4},
    symbol={\(4\)},
    description={four},
    definition={\(3 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{five}{
    name={5},
    symbol={\(5\)},
    description={five},
    definition={\(4 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{six}{
    name={6},
    symbol={\(6\)},
    description={six},
    definition={\(5 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{seven}{
    name={7},
    symbol={\(7\)},
    description={seven},
    definition={\(6 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{eight}{
    name={8},
    symbol={\(8\)},
    description={eight},
    definition={\(7 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{nine}{
    name={9},
    symbol={\(9\)},
    description={nine},
    definition={\(8 + 1\)},
  }
\endgroup

%\makeglossaries
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

Hello World!
\vskip .6\textheight

\printglossary[type=greeksym, style=physsym]
\printglossary[type=nodimennum, style=nodimennum]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) instead of `nomencl`.

- Create separate glossaries for the different kinds of symbols.
- Add keys for any additional fields you need (`dimension`, `unit`, `definition`).
- Create glossary styles as desired. I took the predefined `long3col-booktabs` and `long4col-booktabs` and modified them.
- Add the glossary entries. I locally redefined `\glsdefaulttype` to put many entries in the desired glossary without giving the `type` key for every one. You could just as well load them from different files or create custom macros for the same level of convenience.
- Add all defined entries to the glossaries (so you don't have to use them in the document).

As a reminder: The complete compilation cycle for `glossaries` is `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` (or equivalent). (This is "Option 2" from the manual.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newglossary*{nodimennum}{Dimensionless Numbers}
\newglossary*{greeksym}{Greek Symbols}

\glsaddkey{dimension}
  {--}
  {\glsentrydimension}
  {\Glsentrydimension}
  {\glsdimension}
  {\Glsdimension}
  {\GLSdimension}
\glsaddkey{unit}
  {--}
  {\glsentryunit}
  {\Glsentryunit}
  {\glsunit}
  {\Glsunit}
  {\GLSunit}
\glsaddkey{definition}
  {--}
  {\glsentrydefinition}
  {\Glsentrydefinition}
  {\glsdefinition}
  {\Glsdefinition}
  {\GLSdefinition}
\glssetnoexpandfield{dimension}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\newcommand*\dimensionname{Dimension}
\newcommand*\unitname{Unit}
\newcommand*\definitionname{Definition}

\newglossarystyle{nodimennum}{%
  \glspatchLToutput
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{l p{.35\linewidth} p{.35\linewidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule
    \bfseries \symbolname &
    \bfseries \descriptionname &
    \bfseries \definitionname
    \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} &
    \glsentrydefinition{##1} \tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\glspenaltygroupskip}%
  \fi
}
\newglossarystyle{physsym}{%
  \glspatchLToutput
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{l l l l}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule \bfseries \symbolname &
    \bfseries \descriptionname &
    \bfseries \dimensionname &
    \bfseries \unitname
    \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} &
    \glsentrydimension{##1} &
    \glsentryunit{##1} \tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\glspenaltygroupskip}%
  \fi
}

\begingroup\renewcommand*\glsdefaulttype{greeksym}
  \newglossaryentry{eps0}{
    name={eps0},
    symbol={\(\varepsilon_0\)},
    description={vacuum permittivity},
    dimension={\(\mathrm F / \mathrm L\)},
    unit={\si{\farad\per\meter}},
  }
\endgroup

\begingroup\renewcommand*\glsdefaulttype{nodimennum}
  \newglossaryentry{zero}{
    name={0},
    symbol={\(0\)},
    description={zero},
    definition={the smallest natural number},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{one}{
    name={1},
    symbol={\(1\)},
    description={one},
    definition={\(0 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{two}{
    name={1},
    symbol={\(2\)},
    description={two},
    definition={\(1 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{three}{
    name={3},
    symbol={\(3\)},
    description={three},
    definition={\(2 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{four}{
    name={4},
    symbol={\(4\)},
    description={four},
    definition={\(3 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{five}{
    name={5},
    symbol={\(5\)},
    description={five},
    definition={\(4 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{six}{
    name={6},
    symbol={\(6\)},
    description={six},
    definition={\(5 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{seven}{
    name={7},
    symbol={\(7\)},
    description={seven},
    definition={\(6 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{eight}{
    name={8},
    symbol={\(8\)},
    description={eight},
    definition={\(7 + 1\)},
  }
  \newglossaryentry{nine}{
    name={9},
    symbol={\(9\)},
    description={nine},
    definition={\(8 + 1\)},
  }
\endgroup

\makeglossaries
\glsaddall

\begin{document}

Hello World!
\vskip .6\textheight

\printglossary[type=greeksym, style=physsym]
\printglossary[type=nodimennum, style=nodimennum]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to reproduce your output by adding the option `automake` while including the `glossaries` package in the preamble. I will try to have both the types of glossary entries occupy same width on the page.

Comment: `automake` just runs `makeglossaries` for you, which you can also do manually, see section 1.1 of the `glossaries` documentation. For making both glossaries have the same width, just modify the `longtable` column specification in the glossary styles.