# How to write long nomenclature entries?

Tags: nomenclature

I have to write nomenclature entries which are long (up to 200 words). 
If I write 200 words in one nomenclature entry I didn't get a nomenclature anymore.

How can I solve this problem?

MWE (nomenclature on the last second last PDF page):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% LyX 2.1.0 created this file.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\documentclass[twoside,ngerman,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\synctex=-1
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{calc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% User specified LaTeX commands.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%% Heading lines
\usepackage[headsepline, ilines,automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings 
\clearscrplain 
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot{}

%%%% Inhaltsverzeichnis!
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black] {hyperref}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
\def\indexspace{}
\patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

%text before glossar!
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{%
This text should be written for the entry Schokolade:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\...consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\...sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,\\...no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, \\...no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata\\...sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero \\...eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\par}

\usepackage{babel}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\begin{center}
\vspace*{10cm}
titlepage
\end{center}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}\tableofcontents

\chapter{Einleitung}
In diesem Dokument geht es um Haustiere.
\chapter{Tiere}
Heute ass meine \index{Katze}Katze \nomenclature{Katze}{Haustier} Schokolade und musste daher zum \index{Tierarzt}Tierarzt. \nomenclature{Tiger}{Raubtier}
\nomenclature{Schokolade}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\...consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\...sed diam}
%
\newpage
neue Seite
\newpage
neue Seite
\addpart{Anhang}
\pagestyle{empty} %ohne Seitenzahlen und Kolumnentitel
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]
%
\clearpage 
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Stichwortverzeichnis} 
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex
%
\end{document}
```

I would be very glad if there is a solution, the headings with inner and outer is not obligatory if there is no exact solution I'm happy with a compromise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a macro for the long text. Here's a stripped down example.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\newcommand{\schokoladetext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\...consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\...sed
  diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
  et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,\\...no sea takimata sanctus
  est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
  dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, \\...no
  sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata\\...sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero \\...eos et accusam et
  justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
  takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Einleitung}
In diesem Dokument geht es um Haustiere.
\chapter{Tiere}
Heute ass meine Katze \nomenclature{Katze}{Haustier} 
Schokolade und musste daher zum Tierarzt. \nomenclature{Tiger}{Raubtier}
\nomenclature{Schokolade}{\schokoladetext}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to raise my question related to nomenclature entries. It is given in the post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197248/for-a-group-of-symbols-how-to-get-column-headingsdescription-in-the-next-page . It would be great if I am able to get an answer to that.