# Glossary with three columns and groups

Tags: longtable, glossaries

I want to create a glossary with 3 columns (I got this already) and I want to subdivide it into different subsections (like Roman and Greek letters). The section should be left-aligned and bold.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=15mm,DIV=12,headings=normal,numbers=noendperiod,parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[acronym,toc,automake,nogroupskip]{glossaries} % automake: glossary automatically compiled each time pdflatex is run
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\textwidth} % total width of glossary
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create new symbolslist
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit} % add unit-entry to list of symbols
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit} % field for unit does never expand
\makeglossaries % calls backend to sort and typeset glossries, list of acronyms, list of symbols etc.
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% change the table type to three columns
      \begin{longtable}{lp{0.75\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{1.3cm}}}%
      {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  change the displayed items
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} % symbol
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% description
        & \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline % unit
    }
}


% defining the two sections
\newglossaryentry{header1}{name={Section 1},description={},sort=000,unit={}}
\newglossaryentry{header2}{name={Sectino 2},description={},sort=001,unit={}}

% adding two entries
\newglossaryentry{firstEntry}{name=\ensuremath{a_1},
    sort=a1,
    description={Some description},
    unit={\si{-}},
    type=symbolslist,
    parent=header1}

\newglossaryentry{secondEntry}{name=\ensuremath{b_2},
    sort=b2,
    description={Some description},
    unit={\si{-}},
    type=symbolslist,
    parent=header2}


\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
        \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong,title={List of Important Symbols}]

    Hello World
\end{document}
```

Defining the two "Sections" at the beginning destroys the entries coming afterwards. Everything works fine if I do not define a parent. Can you help me? Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, `\glsdescwidth` is meant to be the width of the `description` column of your glossary (that's why it's called that). It would be clearer to use it as such and set `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{.75\textwidth}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to define how subentries should be displayed. If you add

```latex
\renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
   \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}} &
   \glossentrydesc{##2} &
   \glsunit{##2} \tabularnewline
}%
```

to your definition of `symbunitlong`, the subentries will show up as (I suspect that) you expect.

This is not really a good way to "create sections" in your glossary, though. You should rather create two separate glossaries (e.g. one for Roman and one for Greek symbols). These can then easily be configured and output separately. (If you need a basic example for how to do this, you can have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530586/48973). The question is a different one, but the example shows pretty much what you are looking for, I think.)