# changeing appearance of nomencl

Tags: nomenclature

I'd like to change the appearance of my nomenclature to a design that's closer to the following image, has someone some ideas how to get there?
[image: aim]

right now it looks like:

[image: current state]

My mini example was inspired by: ([How to achieve nomenclature entries like: symbol, Description, Dimension and unit, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl,etoolbox,ragged2e,siunitx}

\newcommand{\insertnomheaders}{\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
    \textbf{Description}\hfill{\textbf{Units}}}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\large\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}{%
                \ifstrequal{#1}{S}{Superscripts}{% 
                    \ifstrequal{#1}{U}{Subscripts}{%   
                        \ifstrequal{#1}{X}{Other Symbols}{}}}}}}]
    \insertnomheaders
}

\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}
\newcommand{\nomwithdim}[4]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
    {\nomdescr{#3}{#4}}}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    \mbox{}
    \nomwithdim{R}{\(a,b,c\)}{half axes of ellipsoid}{\si{m}}

    \printnomenclature%[\textwidth]%[6em]
\end{document}
```