# How to add and change nomenclature entries with subheading like: symbol, description and unit?

Tags: nomenclature, units

I adapted the nomenclature from this post here: [How to achieve nomenclature entries like: symbol, Description, Dimension and unit, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni)
but I had difficulties adapting it for my own purpose.

This is the code I am currently working with:

```
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{\hfill\makebox[2em]{#1\hfill}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\insertnomheaders}{\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
\textbf{Description}\nomunit{\textbf{Units}}}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
\item[\large\bfseries
\ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}}}]
\insertnomheaders}

\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{12cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}
 \newcommand{\nomwithdim}[4]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\nomdescr{#3}\nomunit{#4}}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\nomwithdim{R}{\(a,b,c\)}{half axes of ellipsoid}{\si{m}}
\nomwithdim{R}{\(C\)}{dimensionless coefficient (e.g.\ for drag model)}
\nomwithdim{G}{\( \varepsilon_0 \)}{vacuum permittivity}

\printnomenclature[6em]
\end{document}
```

What I want to have in the end is "Acronyms" with only symbol and description without units and Greek & Roman symbols with symbol description and units.

The original design is fine but I have difficulties with deleting the dimension and for acronyms both dimension and units without getting errors.

[image: This is how it should look like]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. I figured out that changing the code is harder than rewriting it. In case you are interested, here is what I did:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\units}[1]{\hfill\makebox[2em]{#1\hfill}\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\nomsubtitle}[1]{\item[\large\bfseries #1]}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{\def\nomtemp{\csname nomstart#1\endcsname}\nomtemp}

\newcommand{\nomstartR}{\nomsubtitle{Roman Symbols}%
\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
\textbf{Description}\units{\textbf{Unit}}}

\newcommand{\nomstartG}{\nomsubtitle{Greek Symbols}%
\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
\textbf{Description}\units{\textbf{Unit}}}

\newcommand{\nomstartA}{\nomsubtitle{Acronyms}%
\item[\bfseries Acronym]\textbf{Description}}


\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{12cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}

\newcommand{\nomtypeA}[3][]{\nomenclature[A#1]{#2}{\nomdescr{#3}}}
\newcommand{\nomwithunits}[4]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\nomdescr{#3}\units{#4}}} %neuer Befehl zum Gesamtergebnis der Symbole
\newcommand{\nomtypeR}[4][]{\nomwithunits{R#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeG}[4][]{\nomwithunits{G#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}


\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\mbox{}

\nomtypeA{Cd}{Cadmium}
\nomtypeA{\ce{CdAc2}}{Cadmium acetat dihydrate}
\nomtypeA{CdSe}{Cadmium selenide}
\nomtypeA{i.e.}{For example}
\nomtypeA{ODE}{1-Octadecene}
\nomtypeA{QD}{Quantum Dots}
\nomtypeA{Se}{Selenium}
\nomtypeA{TDPA}{Tetradecylphosphonic acid}
\nomtypeA{TOP}{Trioctylphosphine}

\nomtypeG{$\alpha$}{Angle of a triangle}{-}

\nomtypeR{A}{This is a test}{kg}
{end{document}
```