# Add "continued from previous page" in header of second Nomenclature page?

Tags: texmaker, thesis, nomenclature

I based my nomenclature page on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni), and it seems to be working well. However, I would like the second page of it to say "continued from previous page" in the top left, similar to this picture:
[image: Example of what I would like it to look like]

Here is what I have for my List of Symbols page. Please excuse extraneous lines and anything that doesn't make sense, I am a beginner.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{nomencl,etoolbox,ragged2e,siunitx,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\newcommand{\DimensUnits}[2]{\hfill\makebox[8em]{#1\hfill}%
\makebox[4em]{#2\hfill}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\DefinitionCol}[1]{\hfill\parbox[t]{12em}{#1}\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\nomsubtitle}[1]{\item[\large\bfseries #1]}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{\def\nomtemp{\csname nomstart#1\endcsname}\nomtemp}

\newcommand{\nomstartR}{\nomsubtitle{Roman Symbols}%
  \item[\bfseries Symbol]%
  \textbf{Description}\DimensUnits{\textbf{Dimensions}}{\textbf{Units}}}
\newcommand{\nomstartG}{\nomsubtitle{Greek Symbols}%
  \item[\bfseries Symbol]%
  \textbf{Description}\DimensUnits{\textbf{Dimensions}}{\textbf{Units}}}
\newcommand{\nomstartD}{\nomsubtitle{Dimensionless Numbers}%
  \item[\bfseries Symbol]\textbf{Description}\DefinitionCol{\textbf{Definition}}}

\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}
\newcommand{\nomwithdim}[5]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\nomdescr{#3}\DimensUnits{#4}{#5}}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeR}[5][]{\nomwithdim{R#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeG}[5][]{\nomwithdim{G#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\newcommand{\nomtypeD}[4][]{\nomenclature[D#1]{#2}{\nomdescr{#3}\DefinitionCol{#4}}}

\makenomenclature


\begin{document}


\pdfbookmark[0]{List of symbols}{List of symbols}
%\chapter*{List of Symbols}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\mbox{}


\nomtypeR[t_{sol}]{\(t_{sol}\)}{solidification time}{$t$}{\si{s}} %line 412

\nomtypeR[c]{\(c\)}{sound velocity}{$L/t$}{\si{m/s}} %line 425
\nomtypeG[\kappa]{\(\kappa\)}{heat capacity ratio}{$-$}{\si{1}} %line 425
\nomtypeR[R_s]{\(R_s\)}{specific gas constant}{$L^2/t^2$}{\si{J/kg}} %line 425
\nomtypeR[T_g]{\(T_g\)}{gas temperature}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 425

\nomtypeR[\dot m_{G}]{\(\dot m_{G}\)}{gas mass flow rate,room temperature }{$m/t$}{\si{kg/s}} %line 431
\nomtypeR[\dot m_{G,0}]{\(\dot m_{G,0}\)}{gas mass flow rate, elevated temperature}{$m/t$}{\si{kg/s}} %line 431
\nomtypeR[T_0]{\(T_0\)}{room temperature}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 431
\nomtypeR[T_g]{\(T_g\)}{glass transition \linebreak temperature}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 431

\nomtypeR[T_{liq}]{\(T_{liq}\)}{liquidus temperature}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 493
\nomtypeR[T_{rg}]{\(T_{rg}\)}{reduced glass transition temperature}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 490
\nomtypeG[\eta]{\(\eta\)}{viscosity}{$T$}{\si{Pa/s}} %line 490

\nomtypeR[R_c]{\(R_c\)}{critical cooling rate}{$T/t$}{\si{K/s}} %line 507
\nomtypeR[t_x(T)]{\(t_x(T)\)}{?}{$t$}{\si{s}} %line 507
\nomtypeR[T^*]{\(T^*\)}{crystallization nose temperature}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 507
\nomtypeR[t_{x}^{*}]{\(t_{x}^{*}\)}{?}{$T$}{\si{K}} %line 507

\nomtypeR[d_{max}]{\(d_{max}\)}{critical casting thickness}{$L$}{\si{mm}} %line 512

\nomtypeR[I_v]{\(I_v\)}{nucleation rate}{$?$}{\si{?}} %line 521

\nomtypeR[D_{eff}]{\(D_{eff}\)}{effective diffusivity}{$?$}{\si{?}} %line 534

\nomtypeR[k_B]{\(k_B\)}{Boltzmann constant}{$?$}{\si{?}} %line 534

\cleardoublepage           
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols} %% may be this is good.
\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname} 
\printnomenclature[6em]

\end{document}
```

And here is a picture of what it looks like in pdf:

[image: Image of my List of Symbols page]

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Good first question - just one thing: your MWE is almost, but not entirely, W, the documentclass is missing. From the output it does not seem to be a standard `article`, so that may actually be relevant here.

Comment: Yes! I forgot to include the document class. I have included it now. Thank you!

Comment: The `continue` package may be of some help here.